# Qtcreator/ Си/ Вылетает SIGSEGV, не показывает строчку на которой произошел вылет

Tags: c, отладка, qtcreator

[image: Вот сама ошибка]

Как мне понять в каком месте я ошибся?

Comment: Желательно публиковать сообщения об ошибке и код, где она проявляется. Включите исходнюе коды в исполняемую программу (обычно `-g` в  криэйторе не знаю).

Comment: Скопируйте сюда стек вызовов (панель во втором снизу ряду, левее списка точек останова).

Comment: Судя по названиям фунцкий это в библиотеке высыпалось? Что-то с unicode символами пытаетесь делать? Возможно памяти не выделили под символы достаточно (`sizeof(wchar_t) != sizeof(char)` чаще всего). И multy-byte character может достигать длины 6 байт.

Answer (score 1):

Да вы же по стеку то вызовов спуститесь, там и будет строчка, даже так видно что в fscanf_s, это вот где написано Отладчик, уровень